# How to implement XOR encryption in C to send data from Client toServer

Tags: c, encryption, server, client, xor

I'm so confused, I have an XOR encryption Program in c which do encryption and decryption in same program , but i want encryption and decryption to be separate.

Then i want code where client send the data/string message to Server with encryption (XOR) then Server Should receive encrypted string message in c program.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output)
{
 char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
   output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))]; 
 }
}

int main()
{
 char baseStr[1000];

 printf("Enter string:");
 fgets(baseStr, sizeof baseStr, stdin);
 char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
 encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted);
 printf("Encrypted:%s\n\n\n", encrypted);
 char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
 encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted);
 printf("Decrypted:%s\n\n\n", decrypted);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i need a code for sending message from client to server with xor encryption

Comment: Do not try to create your own encryption. For client server communications just use https, everything will be encrypted. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: Show us what you have and what you're struggling with. You have the xor code? What have you done towards the networking code? What is the issue with it? From StackOverflow you will receive a great deal of expert assistance to a well written question, showing you've made an effort. You will receive little help when just asking for someone else to do your work.

Comment: how to send code,, here its not taking my code

Comment: Separating your encryption into encrypt and decrypt functions doesn't make sense, they would be identical. There's nothing to do with sending any result to a server in your code. The first thing to do is find a networking tutorial, and try following it. Feel free to ask any specific questions you have here which you're unable to solve with a simple search.

Comment: i tried with sending message from client to server ... its working,, but when i include this xor program its not sending to server

Comment: @Megha don't put tons of code in comments, it's unreadable, but edit your question instead.

Comment: It seems that you are not familiar with how to ask for help on online forums. Please understand that you need to provide specifics of your implementation in the format and conventions commonly used.

Comment: @Colin__s Using XOR encryption, in fact any do-it-yourself encryption, is not secure and should not be done.

Comment: @Megha So your actual question is not about XOR encryption, but how to send data from one computer to another via the network, right?

Comment: @zaph I appreciate that, but the question at hand isn't whether the encryption is good, or should be used. I have neither endorsed nor condemned it.

Comment: @zaph There is nothing in the question about HTTP, there is mention of client server comms, so if you want to push anything I suggest TLS or SSL. My point still stands, this question is **not** about the strength of encryption.

Comment: using Client and server i need to send text file with encryption

Comment: @Colin__s The question is: "... client send the data/string message to Server .... " and "... want encryption and decryption ...". The most common method using encryption is with HTTPS. If you feel TLS or SSL is mote appropriate supply that help. Simple XOR encryption is a joke and would put users at risk and needs to be avoided.

Comment: @zaph I give up. You win.

Comment: @Colin__s I am not looking for a "win", I am looking out for the users. I feel it is possible to both help the OP and protect the users.

Comment: @Megha You can send a text file from a client to a server with encryption using HTTPS with the file data as the POST data. Another solution is to use [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: You ignore the terminations. `char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)]` add `+1` and in your function you should do a `output[i]=´\0´;` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to align with my thinking on your problem.
I have edited your code a little bit:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output)
{
    char key[] = { 'K', 'C', 'Q' }; //Can be any chars, and any size array
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];
    }
    output[strlen(input)] = '\0';
}
void serverDecryptedText(char* encryptedText, char* decryptedNormalText)
{
    /*Assumed: Server got encryptedText*/
    encryptDecrypt(encryptedText, decryptedNormalText);
    /*You will get original text in decryptedNormalText*/
}
void sendToServerWithEncryption(char* normalText, char* encryptedText)
{
    encryptDecrypt(normalText, encryptedText);
    /*Implement code to send encryptedText to server here */
}
int main()
{
    char baseStr[1000];
    printf("Enter string:");
    scanf("%s",baseStr);

    char *encrypted = (char*)malloc(strlen(baseStr)+1); 
    char *decrypted = (char*)malloc(strlen(baseStr) + 1);

    sendToServerWithEncryption(baseStr, encrypted);

    printf("Encrypted:%s\n\n\n", encrypted);

    serverDecryptedText(encrypted, decrypted);

    printf("Decrypted:%s\n\n\n", decrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no real security in such a simple scheme.

Comment: Yes, its a hint. You've to implement your security scheme.